# How to remove a particular value from an array and then passing the filtered out array to another function in jquery and php

Tags: php, jquery

I am basically using jquery with php and getting some urls through php form in a javascript function and i am giving the users ability to remove particular rows on click of a particular button ; it is performing correctly but now i want the filtered out array to pass it further to next jquery function.
This is my code:

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    //alert("hii");
        $('button').click(function(){
        //alert("hii");
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        //alert(id);
        $("#"+id).remove();

        });
    });

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function opensall() {
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $urlss= trim($_POST['camp_url']);
    $urls = explode("\n", $urlss);
    $i = 1 ;
    $datas="";
    $final_urls=array();

foreach ($urls as $url)
{
    $url = trim($url);
    $parsed = parse_url($url);
    if (empty($parsed['scheme'])) {
        $url = 'http://' . ltrim($url, '/');
}
$id="tr".$i;
$time = time().'c'.$i;
$data = '<tr id="'.$id.'"><td >'.$i.'</td><td id="'.$id.'"><a href="'.$url.'" target="'.$time.'">'.$url.'</a></td><td><button id="'.$id.'" >Delete</button></td></tr>';
$datas .= $data ;

?>

window.open('<?php echo $url;?>', '<?php echo $time;?>')
<?php
    $i++;
    }
    }
?>
}
</script>
```

Comment: Indent that awful thing! :D

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you need an array of URLs to pass to the next Jquery function, and on delete button click you want to remove the corresponding URL.

Please use the javascript array in your `opensall()` function

```
var urlArray = new Array();
```

and assign the url values to this array in your foreach loop,

```
urlArray[$id] = <?php echo $url ?>;
```

To unset the aray on click of the button use the javascript `splice` method.

```
array.splice(id);
```

Please let me know if this answered your question.

Comment: I understood ur answer but using in between php and jquery seems to be confusing for me. Can you provide me the sample code for achieving this??

Comment: Basically i could not understand this part of code "and assign the url values to this array in your foreach loop,

urlArray[$id] = ;"

Comment: Please find this code sniplet, I have inserted my js code in the original code provided by you,

Answer (score 0):

Please find the code provided below, I have inserted my js code in the original code provided by you,

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
//alert("hii");
    $('button').click(function(){
    //alert("hii");
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    //alert(id);
    $("#"+id).remove();
    array.splice(id); // remove the URL array here using javascript splice.
    });
});

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function opensall() {
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$urlss= trim($_POST['camp_url']);
$urls = explode("\n", $urlss);
$i = 1 ;
$datas="";
$final_urls=array(); 
?>
var urlArray = new Array(); // A javascript array started.
<?php
foreach ($urls as $url)
{
$url = trim($url);
$parsed = parse_url($url);
if (empty($parsed['scheme'])) {     
    $url = 'http://' . ltrim($url, '/');
    ?>

    urlArray[<?php echo $i ?>] = <?php echo $url ?>; // assign the javascript variable In between your code

    <?php
}
$id="tr".$i;
$time = time().'c'.$i;
$data = '<tr id="'.$id.'"><td >'.$i.'</td><td id="'.$id.'"><a href="'.$url.'"    target="'.$time.'">'.$url.'</a></td><td><button id="'.$id.'" >Delete</button></td></tr>';
$datas .= $data ;

?>

window.open('<?php echo $url;?>', '<?php echo $time;?>')
<?php
$i++;
}
}
?>
}
</script>
```